# how to add a .sql database to an existing db in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm relatively new at Laravel development and I have a large .sql file to add on my existing db (the DB is a list of city in Italy with their relative lat and long data). Anyone know how can I add the file with a seed?
thank you and sorry for the question :)

Comment: Read about Laravel Migrations:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations
and
Seeding
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/seeding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a .sql file with a seed, you have to use the following approach:

```
DB::unprepared(file_get_contents(database_path('seeds/cities.sql'));
```

This will not work well with very large files.